# .getSystemPortName not working in a Java program

Tags: java, serial-port, comm

I am trying to write a program for creating a gui for plotting data from Serial Port input in Java.

My code is the following:

```
public class SensorGraph {

    static SerialPort chosenPort;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create and configure the window 
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setTitle("Sensor Graph GUI");
        window.setSize(600,400);
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // create a drop-down boc and connect button , then place them at the top of the window
        JComboBox<String> portList = new JComboBox<String>();
        JButton connectButton = new JButton("Connect");
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(portList);
        topPanel.add(connectButton);
        window.add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // populate the drop-down box
        SerialPort[] portNames = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
        for (int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++)
            portList.addItem(portNames[i].getSystemPortName());

        // show the window 
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The problem is that i wanted to have something like :

[image]

and I end up with :

[image]

Is there something wrong with the library of jSerialComm? Why can I not see my SerialPorts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the result of `portNames.length`?
What does the method `portNames[i].getSystemPortName()` return?

Comment: The result is 0 . I am not using an Arduino for example sending data. Is that the problem ? Is there a necessity to be receiving some data in order to find a serial COM port ?

Comment: Can you post the method `SerialPort.getCommPorts()`?

Comment: https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPort.html


static SerialPort[] getCommPorts() Returns a list of all available serial ports on this machine.

Comment: You're supposed to edit the code into your question. That way if the link broke (repo no longer existed or something) this question could still be read and understood by other users